# How do I create a graph of filtered values from a CSV file?

Tags: python, numpy, dataset, graphing

I am trying to create a graph of filtered values from a CSV file. Essentially, I have to filter through all the data from this dataset: https://data.humdata.org/dataset/novel-coronavirus-2019-ncov-cases#
, and tally up how many cases of coronavirus there are for each country (US, Chine, Italy, Germany and Iran), then produce a graph for each country, comparing the number of cases (y-axis) to the date (x-axis).

So far, I have been able to filter the data, and print each line containing the number of cases for that specific location. I have not been able to tally up the total amount for each country or produce a graph that makes sense.

Here is my code so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd



data = pd.read_csv(r'C:*****')

countries = ['China', 'Italy', 'Germany', 'Iran', 'US']
filtered_data = data[data['Country/Region'].isin(countries)]


wanted_values = filtered_data[['Country/Region','1/22/2020','1/23/2020','1/24/2020', 
 '1/25/2020','1/26/2020','1/27/2020','1/28/2020','1/28/2020','1/29/2020',


 '1/30/2020','1/31/2020','2/1/2020','2/2/2020','2/3/2020','2/4/2020','2/5/2020','2/6/2020',
  '2/7/2020',  '2/8/2020','2/9/2020','2/10/2020',
  '2/11/2020','2/12/2020','2/13/2020','2/14/2020','2/15/2020',
  '2/16/2020','2/17/2020','2/18/2020','2/19/2020','2/20/2020','2/21/2020',
  '2/22/2020','2/23/2020',
'2/24/2020','2/25/2020','2/26/2020','2/27/2020','2/28/2020','2/29/2020','3/1/2020',
'3/2/2020','3/3/2020','3/4/2020','3/5/2020','3/6/2020','3/7/2020',
'3/8/2020','3/9/2020','3/10/2020','3/11/2020','3/12/2020','3/13/2020','3/14/2020',
'3/15/2020','3/16/2020','3/17/2020','3/18/2020','3/19/2020',
'3/20/2020','3/21/2020']]


 print(wanted_values.iloc[0])
 print(wanted_values.iloc[1])
 print(wanted_values.iloc[282])
```

There are 283 rows of data that was filtered from the original CSV file, hence the iloc[282].

I'm not too sure where to go from here to be able to graph the number of cases vs. the date for each country/region.

[Here is a screenshot of what the data set looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSMLG.png)

Comment: If you want to plot your data check out [this article](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html) on plotting using Pandas DataFrames.

Comment: @pciunkiewicz I will check that out. Thank you!